# Convert single row into multiple rows Bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Convert a row into multiple rows in bigQuery SQL. 
The number of rows depend on a particular column value (in this case, the value of delta_unit/60):

Source table:

```
ID             time                           delta_unit
101            2019-06-18 01:00:00            60
102            2019-06-18 01:01:00            60
103            2019-06-18 01:03:00            120
```

The ID 102 does recorded a time at 01:01:00 and the next record was at 01:03:00.
So, we are missing a record that should have been 01:02:00 and the delta_unit = 60

Expected table:

```
ID             time                           delta_unit
101            2019-06-18 01:00:00            60
102            2019-06-18 01:01:00            60
104            2019-06-18 01:02:00            60
103            2019-06-18 01:03:00            60
```

A new row is created based on the delta_unit. The number of rows that need to be created will depend on the value delta_unit/60 (in this case, 120/60 = 2)

Comment: Can you provide more examples? The logic is not clear with only one. Or why?

Comment: In the first dataset, ff you look at the time column, you will see that the 01:02:00 is missing in sequence.
And this is represented by the delta_unit, i.e., the last time a record was captured was 2 mins ago (hence the  delta_unit is 120 for 01:03:00 minute)
Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to your problem. I have done the following, first run

```
SELECT max(delta/60) as max_a FROM `<projectid>.<dataset>.<table>`
```

to compute the maximum number of steps. Then run the following loop

```
DECLARE a INT64 DEFAULT 1;
WHILE a <= 2 DO --2=max_a (change accordingly)
INSERT INTO `<projectid>.<dataset>.<table>`  (id,time,delta)
SELECT id+1,TIMESTAMP_ADD(time, INTERVAL a MINUTE),delta-60*a
FROM 
(SELECT id,time,delta
FROM `<projectid>.<dataset>.<table>` 
)
WHERE delta > 60*a;
SET a = a + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Of course this is not efficient enough but it gets the Job done. The IDs and deltas do not finish at the right values yet, they should not be needed. The deltas would end up all at 60 (the column can be deleted) and the IDs can be recreated using the timestamp to get them ordered.

You might try using a conditional expression in [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions) to avoid the loop and only going through the table once.

I have tried

```
INSERT INTO `<projectid>.<dataset>.<table>`  (id,time,delta)
SELECT id+1, CASE
   WHEN delta>80 THEN TIMESTAMP_ADD(time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
   WHEN delta>150 THEN TIMESTAMP_ADD(time, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
   END
   ,60
FROM 
(SELECT id,time,delta
FROM `<projectid>.<dataset>.<table>` 
)
WHERE delta > 60;
```

but fails because only returns the first condition where the when is True. So, I am not sure if it is possible to do it all at once. If you have small tables I would stick to the first one which works fine.

Comment: This is great @aemon4, thanks a ton!
The first solution seems to do the trick (i have not tried the second one yet), my table is pretty large, it is partitioned by the time column (can go up to 150 GB per day). I'll try this solution with the columns that I have and the day with highest records to see how expensive this can be.